# Paypal Express Checkout - More details for the customer

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I use Paypal Express checkout with `checkout.js`
with the [standard javascript code](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) provided by paypal.

Everything works fine and the payment popup looks like this:

[image]

Now my question: Is it possible to add more details about the product to this popup?

Like for example, the name and description for the product?
(This code is not working).

```
return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
  transactions: [
    {
      amount: { total: '{{ entry.itemPreis }}', currency: 'CHF' },
      description: 'this is some description',
      // description: works and shows up in the paypal backend
      // but is not visible to the customer

      title: 'this would be the title' // doesn't work
    }
  ],
});
```

I find the paypal docs to be quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
transactions: [
    {
        amount: { total: '100', currency: 'CHF' },
            item_list: {
            items: [
                {
                name: 'Whateveryoufancy',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum',
                quantity: '1',
                price: '100',
                currency: 'CHF'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```